# How to remove a Tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dotnetnuke

I'm in a bit of a pickle. What I'm trying to achieve is to remove a div IF it is empty and then do what I have to afterwards which is the easy bit. The hard part is trying to remove the empty tags. I'm using DNN and it likes to put in empty tags like p and br. I want to be able to remove them before performing my check. Here is my code so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); //Need to remove all tags. not just P
element.parentNode.removeChild(element); //Doesn't target which child

if( !$.trim( $('#container2Test').html() ).length ) {
    alert("empty");
    $('#container2Test').remove();
    $('#container3Test').css({'width' : '50%', 'background-color' : '#3F0'});
    $('#container3Test').append("This is some content");
}
else{
    alert("not empty");
}
});
```

The html:

```
<div id="container1Test" style="width:30%; height:10em; background-color:#000;">
</div>
<div id="container2Test" style="width:50%; height:10em; background-color:#666;">
    <p></p><br /><p></p>
</div>
<div id="container3Test" style="width:20%; height:10em; background-color:#F66;">
</div>
```

I've tried many options to try and remove the tags but I've had no such luck :( Please help!

Comment: `element` is an array.  (actually a NodeList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your `container2test` block goes, try using `.text()` instead of `.html()`. This will ignore the empty tags that get inserted and focus only on the text content.

Regarding the piece above it, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve. I don't think it's needed if you implement the change I mentioned earlier.

Comment: haha... you're right. changing it to .text() did ignore the empty tags and everything went as expected. Don't even need the code above. Thank you so much for that, and the swift response! Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the solution you'll need... Check out that:

```
var elmsToClear = $('#container1Test, #container2Test, #container3Test');
elmsToClear.each(function(){
    while($(this).find('*:empty').remove().length); // recursivly kill all empty elements
    if(!$(this).find('*').length){ // if no elements left - kill the parent
        alert($(this).attr('id') + ' is empty...');
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{ // there is something in here...
        alert($(this).attr('id') + ' is NOT empty...');
    }
});
```

>>> [The JS-Fiddle of the Problem with Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/T3ggB/) <<<

Greetings ;)

Comment: Great solution, but I have my answer, thanks heaps none the less though!

Answer (score -1):

Notice that `getElementsByTagName` is plural:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var n=0; n < elements.length; n++) {
    var element = elements[n];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element); // should work now
}
```

Comment: I tried using this but it didn't achieve the goal I was achieving. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

There is a [removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild) function.  So why can't you do something like this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
   if(this.innerHTML == ''){
      this.parentNode.removechild(this);
   }
});
```

(Haven't tested this)